# SVM matlab example

Tags: matlab, svm

[code shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZMog.png)
I am trying to implement SVM for classification. The goal is to output the correct grid of origin of a power signal (.wav file). The grids are titled A-I and there are 93 total signals for the training set and 49 practice signals. I have a 93x10x36 matrix of feature vectors. Does anyone know why I get the errors shown? TrainCorrectGrid and Training_Cepstrum1 both have 93 rows so I don't understand what the problem is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[error shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe6qO.png)

The multisvm function is shown here:

```
function [result] = multisvm(TrainingSet,GroupTrain,TestSet)
%Models a given training set with a corresponding group vector and 
%classifies a given test set using an SVM classifier according to a 
%one vs. all relation. 
%
%This code was written by Cody Neuburger cneuburg@fau.edu
%Florida Atlantic University, Florida USA
%This code was adapted and cleaned from Anand Mishra's multisvm function
%found at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33170-multi-class-support-vector-machine/

u=unique(GroupTrain);
numClasses=length(u);
result = zeros(length(TestSet(:,1)),1);

%build models
for k=1:numClasses
    %Vectorized statement that binarizes Group
    %where 1 is the current class and 0 is all other classes
    G1vAll=(GroupTrain==u(k));
    models(k) = svmtrain(TrainingSet,G1vAll);
end

%classify test cases
for j=1:size(TestSet,1)
    for k=1:numClasses
        if(svmclassify(models(k),TestSet(j,:))) 
            break;
        end
    end
    result(j) = k;
end
```

Comment: If you have more than two classes, you should read about [one vs. one and one vs. all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification) SVMs for multiclass classification.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar I have looked at that already but it is rather confusing..I have no idea how I would implement SVM for more than two classes in code. I have classes A through I. Matlab examples only show two class examples

Comment: Why don't you look into [libSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/)?. It uses `one-vs-one` method internally, so that you don't have to care about that. You just provide your data and your multiclass labels. It is compatible with MATLAB too.

Comment: It's really hard to help you if you don't give all the information. Afaik MATLAB doesn't have a `multisvm` function. Where did you get the `multisvm` function? Did you write it? If so, please post the code. The code as text and some sample data would be great, so we can try to reproduce the error. An image with only part of the code it's not very helpful though.

Comment: @SebaArriagada I apologize. I have posted the multisvm function code.

Comment: @user6132277 I wrote the code you posted in the image and run it with same dimensions matrix as the ones you posted in the workspace image (using random features) and the `multisvm` function doesn't throw any of the errors you mentioned in the comments in the answer below. It trains the models and classify the test samples correctly. Are you using the MATLAB `svmtrain` function? Can you run `which svmtrain` in the console?.

Comment: @SebaArriagada do you see anything wrong with how I entered into the multisvm function?

Comment: @user6132277 yes, i just realized that actually there is an error in the first parameter in the image. You should remove the (4) after the variable name.

Comment: @SebaArriagada wow, thank you. That fixed my problem and I am now getting an output but they are numbers, whereas I need letters A - I. Is it safe to say 1 is mapping to A, 2 to B, 3 to C, etc?

Comment: yes, that mapping should work

Comment: @user6132277 As @Harjatin said, that should work since the `unique` function done in the first line in the `multisvm` sorts the labels alphabetically. You can add the `u` variable as output in `multisvm`, changing the first line in the function for: `function [result, u] = multisvm(TrainingSet,GroupTrain,TestSet)` and use `u` has a map: `u(1)` should return 'A', `u(2)` should return 'B' and so on. I'm glad you managed to fix the problem.

Comment: @SebaArriagada thank you very much guys. I got it working. It is much appreciated.

Comment: are there any parameters I can change in the code for better performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVM's are typically one vs one or one vs all classifiers. However there exist ways to tweak them to achieve multiclass classification.

[This](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39352-multi-class-svm) package implements one such way.

Here is sample code to use the package

```
TrainingSet=[ 1 10;2 20;3 30;4 40;5 50;6 66;3 30;4.1 42]; 
TestSet=[3 34; 1 14; 2.2 25; 6.2 63]; 
GroupTrain=[1;1;2;2;3;3;2;2]; 
results = multisvm(TrainingSet, GroupTrain, TestSet); 
disp('multi class problem'); 
disp(results);
```

Comment: what is GroupTrain in that example?

Comment: They are the classes assigned to feature vectors

Comment: there is also no explanation of what the training and test sets are representing..please explain that sample code

Comment: my training data feature vectors are a 93X512 matrix. The 93 represents the 93 separate training signals

Comment: 'TrainingSet' is the set of feature vectors on which the SVM is to be trained, with the output classes given in the 'GroupTrain' vector. Whereas 'TestSet' is the set on which the trained SVM is tested and the classes assigned to the test set are returned in the 'results' vector

Comment: I am entering my data correctly but I am getting an error that says 'Error using svmtrain: Y and training must have the same number of rows.

Comment: The other error is 'Error in multisvm: models(k) = svmtrain(TrainingSet,G1vAll);'

Comment: My 'TrainingSet' and 'GroupTrain' have the same number of rows. The only difference is my 'GroupTrain' is made up of 93 by 1 char since the classes are grids of origin: a through i

Comment: Update your question and add sample data

Comment: If the answer was useful. Please consider accepting the answer and up voting it :)

Comment: Do you know how multisvm is working behind the scenes? How is it making decisions?

Comment: It trains multiple SVMs, each making a yes or no decision. The SVM which is most confident of it's decision is  considered to make the final choice. Please up vote the answer, if it helped you.